# R select column based on row value

Tags: r

I have found multiple answers where one can select a row based on a value of a column, but I need the reverse. Consider this example:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- readr::read_table2("Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
TRUE         TRUE        TRUE       TRUE    TRUE
TRUE         TRUE        TRUE       TRUE    TRUE
TRUE         TRUE        FALSE       TRUE    FALSE
TRUE         TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE
TRUE       TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE
TRUE       TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE")
```

How can I get the columns or column names which have the values `FALSE`, considering I know it is in the third row.

I tried something like this: `df[3,df[3,]==FALSE]`, but this gives me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines like this:

```
df <- readr::read_table2("Location       Site     Species    Date     Time
                          TRUE         TRUE        TRUE       TRUE    TRUE
                          TRUE         TRUE        TRUE       TRUE    TRUE
                          TRUE         TRUE        FALSE       TRUE    FALSE
                          TRUE         TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE
                          TRUE       TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE
                          TRUE       TRUE        TRUE     TRUE    TRUE")
which(df == FALSE, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2] #gives you the col numbers
```

The argument `arr.ind`, if True, gives you the array indices from which you can extract the column numbers

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i am looking for. Need to wait a couple of minutes to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(where(~ any(. == FALSE))) %>%
  names()

[1] "Species" "Time"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This also answers my question. Nico was a bit faster though.

Comment: No it's ok, your welcome. Glad it has been useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few options :

Base R -

```
#1. Using colSums
names(df)[colSums(!df) > 0]
#Also
#names(df)[colSums(df) != nrow(df)]

#2. Using `Filter`
names(Filter(function(x) any(!x), df))
#Also
#names(Filter(function(x) !all(x), df))

#3. Using `sapply`
names(df)[!sapply(df, all)]
```

With `purrr` :

```
#1. Using `keep`
names(purrr::keep(df, ~any(!.x)))

#2. Using `discard`
names(purrr::discard(df, all))
```

Comment: These are great! in particular the last example of `purrr` with `discard` making use of the fact that `all` returns `TRUE` if all values are `TRUE` and then `discard` them. Truly artful, thank you Ronak Shah for constantly inspiring us.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. these also answer my question. Wish I could mark multiple answers

Answer (score 1):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select_if(~ any(!.)) %>%
  names
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
apply(df, 2, function(df) which (df %in% FALSE))
```

Output:

```
$Location
integer(0)

$Site
integer(0)

$Species
[1] 3

$Date
integer(0)

$Time
[1] 3
```

The number indicates the number of row.